# hasClass() is not working for a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am testing using jasmine-karma at the moment.

There is one testing scenario:

1. One element is clicked and highlighted
2. After it is clicked and highlighted, it will have a new `class` attribute, its html will be changed from `<a xlink:href="#" data-lrn-index="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="Response area" aria-checked="false">` to `<a xlink:href="#" data-lrn-index="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="Response area" aria-checked="true" class="lrn-selected">`

I have managed to locate this element with this jQuery, `$("a[data-lrn-index='0']")`, but this jQuery will return `false`, `$("a[data-lrn-index='0']").hasClass("lrn-selected")`

From this element HTML, it clearly shows it has a `class = ("lrn-selected")`, why cannot jQuery return true?

Comment: When you checked the element $("a[data-lrn-index='0']") on run time, does that it have the class "lrn-selected" ?

Comment: @BryanLoresto, yeah it does its class lrn-selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

> The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an
>   element, even if other classes also are. For example, given the HTML
>   above, the following will return true:

Things to check:

1. Make sure there is no other javascript error
2. Make sure your code is working to apply [addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) function.
3. Use `debugger` and check developer toolbar to debug the function which is applying this class

Please check below example:

```js
$("a[data-lrn-index='0']").click(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass('lrn-selected')) {
        $(this).html('Yes, I had that class');
        $(this).removeClass('lrn-selected');
    }
    else {
        $(this).html('Class removed');
        $(this).addClass('lrn-selected');
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Toggle click for class availability:</p>
<a  href="#" data-lrn-index="0" role="checkbox" aria-label="Response area" aria-checked="false">Click here to check class</a>
```